# Setting a UIIImage object to a NSMutableDictionary not working for me

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, nsmutabledictionary

I'm having quite a hard time trying to save a UIImage to a NSMutableDictionary, I'm trying to save an image to this dictionary with temporary values (in case the user doesn't want to save them). The NSMutableDictionary is initialized in the viewDidLoad method like this:

```
     NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     self.tempValues = dict;
```

And I can perfectly store NSStrings from UITextFields but when I tried to set images from a UIImagePickerController, they have a nil value in the Dictionary.

Here's the method that's giving me problems:

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker          didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        UIImage *shrunkenImage = shrinkImage(chosenImage, CGSizeMake(115, 115));
        UIImage *listImage = shrinkImage(shrunkenImage, CGSizeMake(44, 44));

        [tempValues setObject:shrunkenImage forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kDetailImageIndex]];
        [tempValues setObject:chosenImage forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kFullImageIndex]];
        [tempValues setObject:listImage forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kTableImageIndex]];

        if ([tempValues objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kTableImageIndex]] != nil) {
            NSLog(@"The image exists in tempValues");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"The image in tempValues is in fact nil.");
        }

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

When this runs, the @"The image in tempValues is in fact nil." message gets printed to the console..

If I set this images directly to a property of the object that they will later be saved on, (that is, once the user presses "Save") I can perfectly work with them and they're saved correctly, so chosenImage, shrunkenImage and listImage in fact hold an image. That would look something like this:

```
     object.fullImage = chosenImage;
     object.detailImage = shurnkenImage;
     object.tableImage = listImage;        //These work
```

Any one knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try logging tempValues just before your if statement and see what you get.  I don't see anything wrong in your code that populates the dictionary.

Comment: By logging tempValues you mean printing its values to the console?

Comment: Oh you were right. tempValues was initialized in viewDidLoad, but for some reason I was setting it to nil in the viewWillDisappear method. So when the Image Picker tried to use it, there was no tempValues to set an object to.. Never would've thought of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried but try something like following.

use "String value" instead of using "Number" for Key value.

[tempValues setObject:shrunkenImage forKey:[NSString .....]];